# python script in cron

Tags: python, cron, raspberry-pi3

I try to start cron with my python script:

crontab -e

`55 10 * * * /usr/bin/python /home/vadim/5720Stab/5720Check.py`

in log file I see that script is run, but no work
when I try to start another script:

`00 05 * * * /usr/bin/python /home/vadim/3458Stab/sn20by.py`

this script is work

both scripts work when I start from console.

my first script need to work near 2 hour

my second script work near 10 min.

Comment: `cron` may works code with different privileges and as different user.

Comment: you start first script at `10:55 AM` and second at `05:00 AM` - are you sure you check results at `05:00 AM`?

Comment: maybe use some `log` or file to save some information in file when you run in cron - maybe you will see if it use correct values and use `try/expcet` to catch errors and save it in `log`/`file` - and this way you can see if code in cron works as you expect.